# Facebook graph search, graph API and FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

This is a newbie question (I am sorry for misunderstanding). Is there a connection between Facebook Graph Search (in natural language), Graph API and FQL? In others terms, do we need FQL when a natural language search API is or will be available.Or can FQL, Graph API and Facebook Graph search do exactly the same job?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same at all.

The Graph API and FQL support *reading* (basically) the same kind of data. FQL is a more “SQL-like” approach, but it can not *create* any data – for every “write” action you will have to use the Graph API.

And although the Graph API provides [some search capabilities](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/), they are quite limited (and IMHO not very useful most of the time).

And the Facebook Graph Search is only available on facebook.com as of yet, there is no API that you could use to leverage its functionality within your own apps.

Comment: Thanks CBore. In terms of coverage (accessible data of the graph) and accuracy which can be better FQL (for select queries) or Facebook Graph search . Thank you.